# How long were the differentiation rules developed?

Tags: derivatives, reference-request, math-history, book-recommendation

I would like to know how long were the differentiation rules developed, and how much effort was poured into it. In general, I would like to have some historical context before I delve at differentiation rules. Books or other resources would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'd start from the wikipedia page on the history of calculus: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_calculus

Comment: Many godd books about the historical development of the calculus; see e.g. Margaret Baron, [The Origins of the Infinitesimal Calculus](https://books.google.it/books?id=OcTSBQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover) (1969).

Comment: For some references related to the Newton/Leibniz era, see [here](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=5288486). Probably the most useful general books are Boyer's [**The History of the Calculus and Its Conceptual Development**](https://archive.org/details/TheHistoryOfTheCalculusAndItsConceptualDevelopment) and Edwards' [**The Historical Development of the Calculus**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0387943137). However, if you're concerned with the effort in learning the short-cut rules, you may want to try continuing to evaluate all the derivatives from the limit definition.